# JQuery/HTML : How to provide .click function for an element's multiple ids?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this ajax success function:

```
success: function (data){

        var str = JSON.stringify(data);
        var obj = JSON.parse(str);
    for(var i= 1; i<=obj.length-1;i++)
        {  
          $('#Name').append(obj[i].Name + "<br>"); 
          $(this).attr('id',obj[i].Id);
          $('#this.id').click(function(){
          window.location.href = "test.html";
            })
        }
```

HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover " id= "TableData" border : "1 px solid black">
<tr>
    <td>Product Name </td>
    <td id="Name"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to provide a link to every id of the Name.
For example: The output is like this:

ABC0 
ABC1 
ABC2 
ABC3

I want to link every ABC to another page using .click() property of jquery.
How do I achieve this? The given code is not working.
Please Help.

Comment: What you mean by `$('#this.id')`

Comment: I mean the id for that Name. This is the area I'm confused. Hence the question. I am trying to provide unique id for every ABC (see output).

Comment: What you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to link every ABC to another page using .click() property of jquery.

Comment: Show us the proper html code and what are all the ID's you need to manipulate?

Comment: This is the proper HTML. Only head and body tags aren't shown :P The id's are dependent of the length of JSON data received.

Comment: Check this `$('#this.id')` in your script.

Comment: Replace `$('#this.id')` with `$('#' + this.id)` and try

Comment: Nope. Not working @Patel

Answer (score 0):

You could use `startsWith` attribute selector. Here delegating it to `document` level so no need to set it in any kind of loop:

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^=ABC]', function(){
    // do stuff with 'this.id'
});
```

Comment: Please check this `'[id^=ABC]'`

Comment: @JohnR What i need to check?

Comment: It has to be like this only `'[id^="ABC"]'` right? Am I right or wrong?

Comment: @JohnR In this case, both work but ya it is usually better practice to quote it, handling specific IDs

Answer (score 0):

I can see few issues in you code, you cannot have multiple instance of ID on the same page. I would rather use a class for this. Plus I assume
I dont understand your question 100% but I think you are trying to add a click event on all the td. Rather than this add a data attribute called data-link to all the relaveant td and add a single click element on the main table so that when the table is clicked the event is fired. Then use event.target to find the element that was clicked on and check if it has the relevant data-attribute, if it has the attr data-link then you can extract the value and redirect it.

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#mainTable").click(function(event){
       if(event.target.hasAttribute("data-link")){
         //this is where you would have your code
         console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-link'));
        }
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can assign a common class to each link and simply add click event for that class like :

```
success: function (data){
        var str = JSON.stringify(data);
        var obj = JSON.parse(str);
    for(var i= 1; i<=obj.length-1;i++)
        {  
          var node= $('<a class="linknav">'+obj[i].Name+'</a><br>')
          node.attr('id',obj[i].Id);
          $('#Name').append(node); 
        }
}

$(document).on('click','.linknav',function(){   
window.location.href = "test.html";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for accessing all the elements ID's starts with `ABC`.

Code snippets:

```
$("[id^='ABC']").click(function(){
        window.location.href = "test.html";
    });
```

And this also

```
success: function (data){

    var str = JSON.stringify(data);
    var obj = JSON.parse(str);
    for(var i= 1; i<=obj.length-1;i++)
    {  
        $('#Name').append(obj[i].Name + "<br>"); 
        $(this).attr('id',obj[i].Id);           
    }
    //...
```

Answer (score -1):

What's the result of $(this)? Where does that point to? Have you tried checking it with a console.log?
Also, $("#this.id") is definitely wrong, you're searching for elements with id="this" and class="id", that probably don't exist. You should probably replace that with ("#" + obj[i].Id).
Aside from this, I don't understand well what $(this) does for you. You're adding plain text in the  with id="Name", but then how do you set an id for them? Have you tried doing an append wich already states both Name and Id? Something like

```
$('#Name').append('<span id="' + obj[i].Id + '">' + obj[i].Name + '</span><br>');
$('#' + obj[i].Id).click(function(){window.location.href = "test.html";})
```

Comment: `#this.id` will select `<span id="this" class="id"></span>`